# How does Hibernate check wheather of basic type attribute for @Entity is used or not?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, annotation-processing

I would like to repeat a behavior of annotations like @Entity in Hibernate, @Override, e.t.c, to display warnings in coding time:

I making the ORM library for working with Clickhouse DB, and i created my own annotation @Table, identifying classes related tables in database

Clickhouse only supports basic types like Integers, Boolean, Dates e.t.c, so i would like to check at coding time, does the user of my library use valid data types, or not, like it implemented in Hibernate

How difficult is this task and where should I start?

[image]

Comment: Does annotation processors also uses for this purpose?